# Rails 4 is not saving into the database with this method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Trying to save parameters from url into a database.

I have a link:

```
- @kits.each do |kit|
  = link_to 'Submit Video', new_challenge_path(kit: kit)
  #this will append a new parameter into the url
```

The link goes to a form page with this:

```
= simple_form_for @challenge, html: { class: "form-horizontal" } do |f|
  = f.input :video_title
  = f.input :video_url
  = f.input :video_desc, as: :text
  = f.button :submit, "Upload video"
```

In my controller, I have this:

```
def create
  @challenge = Challenge.new(challenge_params)
  @challenge.kit_id = params[:kit]

  respond_to do |format|
    if @challenge.save
      format.html { redirect_to @challenge, notice: 'Challenge was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @challenge }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @challenge.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_challenge
    @challenge = Challenge.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def challenge_params
    params.require(:challenge).permit(:video_title, :video_url, :video_desc, :kit_id)
  end
```

Association between kit and challenge

```
class Challenge < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :kit, counter_cache: true
end

class Kit < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :challenges
end
```

The parameter doesn't save into the `:kit_id`. Doesn't this: `@challenge.kit_id = params[:kit]` supposed to take care of saving it?

Comment: what association between `Kit` and `Challenge`?

Comment: @OlegSobchuk I've updated the post to add associations between the two

Comment: new_challenge_path goes into new method of the controller, hence your @challenge.kit_id = params[:kit], should be pasted in your new method.

Answer (score 1):

You are right to do the `kit_id` assignment in controller, not in the form, since doing so in the form (even by means of using the hidden field) is not secure, because changing the value of a hidden_field is just a matter of inspecting the elements of the page.

What you are doing wrong, is I assume that `params[:kit]` is just `nil`.

You would probably want to use `params[:kit_id]`.

If that won't help, put `binding.pry` here:

```
  # ... code omitted
  @challenge.kit_id = params[:kit]
  binding.pry
  # ... code omitted
```

and check the value of `params` in opened console.

Comment: if I use `params[:kit_id]`, then does that mean I need to change my link so the url will have `?kit_id=`?

Comment: Also, I just added `binding.pry` to my existing code, but I just got an error: `undefined method 'pry'`

Comment: Also, I'm looking at the console, and it shows `kit_id` parameters, but it doesn't show it in the `INSERT INTO "challenges"`

Comment: @hellomello, what if you change to `kit_id=`, `params[:kit_id]` and in controller do `@challenge.kit_id = params[:kit_id].to_i`?

Comment: just tried, it. I just get 0 as the `kit_id` in the database

Comment: I think the problem might be in the fact, that you pass parameter to action new, but try to use it in action create, not sure if you have it then. May be try to move assignment of the kit_id from create action to new?

Comment: I got it working if I added `= f.input :kit_id, as: :hidden, input_html: { value: params[:kit_id].to_i }` to the view... =\ I'm not sure if the create action is getting the parameters form the URL. Does it not get it on submit? I'm not sure. I tried to move `@challenge.kit_id = params[:kit_id].to_i` into `new` action, but didn't work either.

Comment: I wish I was able to do it the other way